# Session variable between multiple requests in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, fork, metaprogramming

I am in my rails app and I am setting the value of the session in the child procedure in a controller method and then redirecting to a static page which finally redirects to my final controller/action method. Setting the session in the child procedure does not give me the value back in the final controller action which I land. I was using flash earlier but that din't work too so I decided to use session in my multiple resuests. Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

```
child_proc = Proc.new do
  session['ashish'] = "abbbbsb"
  .......
end

fork do
  sleep 1 #just giving enough time for the request to return

  child_proc.call

  exit #it will only exit the chld proc
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `fork`, you are essentially starting a new ruby process with it's own variables. This new process DOES NOT share the same memory as it's parent. It can communicate with the parent but I am not going to explain how here.

Look at this example:

```rb
var = 0
child_proc = Proc.new do
  puts 'from proc:  ' + var.to_s
  var += 1
end

child_proc.call
puts 'after call: ' + var.to_s

pid = fork do
  child_proc.call
end
Process.wait(pid)
puts 'after fork: ' + var.to_s
```

The output is:

```rb
from proc:  0   # main process
after call: 1   # main process 
from proc:  1   # forked process
after fork: 1   # main process
```

Which proves that the code in the fork copies the variables but does not change it in the parent. Even if you repeat the part that forkes, add sleeps and etc. you will still get `1`.

I can't really fix your code, but I am trying to show that this approach is not optimal. Any changes to variables the forked process affect only itself and would not propagate to the main process.

Maybe what you should do instead is deep copy the session variable in a class variable (`@sth`) and only use the copied variable afterwards and the session variable will available in the next request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Can I somehow save the session in the child process which would in turn save it the DB and then retrieve it? I tried session.save in my controller and it dint do the job.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that child process? I think it is a wrong approach and you should design your code in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

i honestly have no idea what your code should be
but assuming you are using rails, and save sessions - you are inside the controllers.

using session in controllers is easy and always working.

#### Just a Controller

```
class PaymentController

  def success
    session[:payment_success] = true
    session[:payment_token] = params[:token]
    redirect_to enable_features_path, status: 303
  end

  def enable_features
    if session[:payment_success]
      current_user.wanted_featurues.find_each(&:enable)
    end
    redirect_to root_path, status: 302
  end
```

#### somewhere in root_path template

```
%h1=session[:payment_token]
```

this should work

Comment: i am trying to set the session in the Proc which is called from the forked process in the controller, redirecting to a static page and then to the controller action where the session variable value which i tried to set is not available. thats the issue which i am facing.

Comment: why procs in controller, why redirect to static pages? anyways - session ain't lost, so its working. maybe your proc is kinda off. where is the whole controller logic ?

Comment: redirect to static page is for the backend to complete the operation. The controller logic is to perform a backedn operation which involves httpd restarts so there is a static page involved. I see that session variable which I am setting in the forked call is not being returned to the parent process. is there a way to solve this??

Comment: u restart the http during the redirects? that will kill all sessions imo